# How to prove that a function is in $L^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f_{n}\in L^{2}([0,1]), f$ is Lebesgue measurable function on $[0,1]$. Assume

1. $\int_{E}f_{n} \to \int_{E}f $ for all measurable sets $E\subset [0,1]$.
2. $\sup\int_{[0,1]}|f_{n}|^{2}dx\leq M$ for some constant $M$.

Prove that: $f\in L^{2}([0,1])$

I have no idea how to do it. From assumption 2 I can prove that $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly absolutely continuous. But how to use assumption 1?

Comment: Yes. It was a typo.

Comment: Are you aware that $L^2([0,1])$ is a Banach space? Try using the triangle inequality, with $|f|_{L^2} \leq |f-f_n|_{L^2} + |f_n|_{L^2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\int_{E}|f|&=\int_{E\cap(f\geq 0)}f-\int_{E\cap(f<0)}f\\
&=\lim_{n}\left(\int_{E\cap(f\geq 0)}f_{n}-\int_{E\cap(f<0)}f_{n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n}\int_{E}\text{sgn}(f)f_{n}.
\end{align*}
By switching $f_{n}$ to $\text{sgn}(f)f_{n}$, we still have $\text{sgn}(f)f_{n}\in L^{2}[0,1]$ and $\sup_{n}\int_{[0,1]}|\text{sgn}(f)f_{n}|^{2}dx\leq M$. So we can assume without of generality that

1. $\int_{E}f_{n}\rightarrow\int_{E}|f|$.
2. $\sup_{n}\int_{[0,1]}|f_{n}|^{2}\leq M$.

The first assumption implies that $\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}\varphi\rightarrow\int|f|\varphi$ for any simple function $\varphi$. However, $|\varphi|$ is still a simple function, so
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]}|f\varphi|=\lim_{n}\int f_{n}|\varphi|\leq\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\|\varphi\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\leq M\|\varphi\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}.
\end{align*}

For every $g\in L^{2}[0,1]$, choose a sequence of simple function $(\varphi_{N})$ such that $\|g-\varphi_{N}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\rightarrow 0$ and $\lim_{N}\varphi_{N}(x)=g(x)$ a.e., then Fatou's lemma gives
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]}|fg|\leq\liminf_{N}\int_{[0,1]}|f\varphi_{N}|\leq\liminf_{N}M\|\varphi_{N}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}=M\|g\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}.
\end{align*}

Now we truncate $f$ to $f\chi_{|f|\leq N}$ for a fixed $N$, so that $f\chi_{|f|\leq N}\in L^{2}[0,1]$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{2}\chi_{|f|\leq N}\right)^{1/2}=\sup\left\{\int_{[0,1]}|f|\chi_{|f|\leq N}|g|: \|g\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\leq 1\right\}
\end{align*}
which shows that
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{2}\chi_{|f|\leq N}\right)^{1/2}\leq M.
\end{align*}
Now taking $N\rightarrow\infty$ and using monotone convergence theorem we obtain
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}=\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\leq M<\infty.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_{n}(g)=\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}g$ for $g\in L^{2}[0,1]$, so the second condition says that the operators $T_{n}$ are uniformly bounded, that is, $\|T_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]\rightarrow L^{2}[0,1]}\leq M$ for all $n=1,2,...$

Banach-Alaoglu theorem implies that $T_{n}\rightarrow T$ weakly for some $T\in(L^{2}[0,1])^{\ast}=L^{2}[0,1]$, say,
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}g\rightarrow\int_{[0,1]}\varphi g,\quad g\in L^{2}[0,1]
\end{align*}
for some $\varphi\in L^{2}[0,1]$. Putting $g=\chi_{E}$ for any measurable set $E\subseteq[0,1]$ one obtains
\begin{align*}
\int_{E}f=\int_{E}\varphi
\end{align*}
which implies that $f(x)=\varphi(x)$ a.e. and hence $f\in L^{2}[0,1]$.

Note that we have both
\begin{align*}
\int_{(f>\varphi)}(f-\varphi)&=0,\\
\int_{(f<\varphi)}(\varphi-f)&=0,
\end{align*}
and hence $\{f\ne\varphi\}$ is of measure zero.

Comment: Thank you. This is clearer but I accepted the proof which is more of the style of real analysis.